# IntelliJ: How to disable 'auto fetch'?

Tags: intellij-idea

Although I never set 'auto fetch', My IntelliJ IDE is automatically do fetch.
Here is my Event log.
[image]

I want to make this function disabled. How to stop it?

Comment: Check these options https://i.imgur.com/kshKHsB.png

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If you have the **GitToolBox** plugin:

Go to `File` → `Settings` → `Version Control` → `GitToolBox` → `Auto Fetch` → `Auto Fetch`

[image]

Comment: works flawlessly