# IntelliJ: how to disable git auto fetch for git submodules

Tags: intellij-idea

I use some git submodules in my project, and I never need to fetch the repositry automatically, only if I wanna update the submodules which the main repo depends on.

Is there any way to disable git auto fetch for git submodules? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69292979/intellij-how-to-disable-auto-fetch) can only disable auto fetch feature of the whole project.

Comment: Do you use Git ToolBox plugin?

Comment: I figure it out with Git ToolBox plugin!

Comment: @Laffery could you share the answer please?

Comment: @AgostBiro Hi, go to `File` → `Settings` → `Version Control` → `GitToolBox` → `GitToolBox Project` → `Auto Fetch` → `Auto Fetch Exclusions`, then add exclusions for your submodules.